# What is the equation for damage in Warframe?

Tags: warframe

Taking into account a weapon's base damage, and any modifiers from modules to include regular damage, armor-piercing damage, elemental damage, and the mitigation from an enemy's shield and armor, what is the equation for how damage is calculated in Warframe?

Comment: The TLDR is "it's complicated". The members of the Warframe community that have done the most in-depth investigations of how damage is calculated have made an [Excel spreadsheet](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_Calculator) you can use to calculate how much damage a given weapon does with given mods.

Comment: Also see here: https://forums.warframe.com/index.php?/topic/5812-damage-shields-mods-enemies-and-you/

Answer (score 4):

If you're here from the future, the damage calculator pointed out by [Oblivious Sage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/30241/oblivious-sage) is outdated as of Damage 2.0. Warframe's wikia site has [an up-to-date, extensive paragraph](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_2.0#Damage_Calculation) on damage calculation, along with formulas.

The system is quite complex, but the gist is:

- Enemies (and NPCs, and warframes) are made of "health materials" - ie. different types of health, shields and armor.
- Every "health material" applies different multiplier against different damage types.
- When you attack, the final damage within your attack is calculated separately for each damage type.

  - Health is a plain, old health bar. If it's depleted, the enemy dies.
  - Shields is a separate health bar that serves as a protection for health bar. If it's depleted, the damage goes to health.
  - Armor is **not** a health bar. It adds its own multipliers on top of health's multiplier (cumulatively) *and* reduces damage the health takes. However,

    - the more armor the enemy has, the more weight armor's multiplier has over health's multiplier,
    - damage types strong against armor reduce that protection (dealing more damage), while damage types weak against armor increase that protection (dealing less damage) - on top of the damage multiplier.