# How do Grineer damage resistances work?

Tags: warframe

In damage 2.0, Grineer soldiers have different damage resistances and vulnerabilities on their flesh and armour. For instance, a Trooper has a 25% resistance to Slash damage from his Ferrite Armour, and a 25% vulnerability to the same Slash damage from having Cloned Flesh.

How do those stack?

Answer (score 1):

There's an [extensive paragraph describing the damage calculation on the wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_2.0#Damage_Calculation).

The short version is: multiplicatively with weights.

The slightly-less-short version is: armor adds its own multipliers on top of health's multiplier (cumulatively) and reduces damage the health takes. However,

- the more armor the enemy has, the more weight armor's multiplier has over health's multiplier,
- damage types strong against armor reduce that protection (dealing more damage), while damage types weak against armor increase that protection (dealing less damage) - on top of the damage multiplier.

(Copied from my answer to a [similar, but much broader, question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127004/what-is-the-equation-for-damage-in-warframe).)